# Google map initialization

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i'm using google maps in my app
i can initialize google maps but i have noticed that the initalize map function is executed twice

Code

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXX&libraries=drawing&callback=InitializeMap&language=ar"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var Lan = getParameterByName('Lat');// get lat from Querystring
            var Long = getParameterByName('Lng');
            InitializeMap(Lan, Long);

        }); function InitializeMap(Lat, Long) {
            alert('Start');
}
```

the alert shows twice 
is that normal 
what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is executed twice because you have initialized twice once in url "callback" and the other one in script. I have removed the Initialized Map function in callback, now it will trigger only once

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXX&libraries=drawing&language=ar"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var Lan = getParameterByName('Lat');// get lat from Querystring
            var Long = getParameterByName('Lng');
            InitializeMap(Lan, Long);

        }); function InitializeMap(Lat, Long) {
            alert('Start');
}
```